# How can I unit test Future<void> function in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I have Future function called addRating that add data to Firestore, I am new to testing in flutter, how do I achieve it?

Function I want to test:

```
Future<void> addRating(RatingModel rating) async {
  await _firestore.collection('rating').doc(rating.ratingId).set(rating.toJson());
}
```

What I have tried:

```
final firestore = FakeFirebaseFirestore();
test('can add to firestore', () async{
  RatingRepository ratingRepository = RatingRepository(firestore: firestore);
  RatingModel model = RatingModel(feedback: 'test', merchantId: '1', orderId: '1', rating: 1, ratingId: '1');
  await expectLater(()async{await ratingRepository.addRating(model);}, isNull);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. The idea of using `await` is correct. You could do the following

```
final firestore = FakeFirebaseFirestore();
test('can add to firestore', () async{
  RatingRepository ratingRepository = RatingRepository(firestore: firestore);
  RatingModel model = RatingModel(feedback: 'test', merchantId: '1', orderId: '1', rating: 1, ratingId: '1');
  await ratingRepository.addRating(model);
  expect(...); // Whatever condition should be fullfilled afterwards. 
});
```

This works because the test function itslef is marked as `async`, allowing you to use await like that inside the function body.

The last line of course depends on your use case. Should a rating be increased? Should it be stored somewhere?

Comment: Actually this code is in rating repository, therefore there is no direct impact on UI, because the test file done in the rating repository package, what should I put if I expect nothing? or I expect null?

Comment: If your function does not change the objects and only impacts the UI, then you don't need to write `expect` at all in the above test case. But then your test case would not make much sense.

If you wanted to test the UI change itself, you would need to use a different approach. Use `testWidgets`, pump a widget and observe it. I think it would be better to open a different question for that if you need to

Answer (score 0):

I think If you are expecting nothing then you just need to verify that the function is called:

```
verify(()async{await ratingRepository.addRating(model);})
```

Comment: the result is 'Used on a non-mocktail object'